# Building microservices with ASN.1 instead of JSON or Protobuf?

Tags: json, microservices, asn.1

Why isn't ASN.1 used for communication among microservices?

What are technical reasons for choosing JSON or Protobuf instead of ASN.1?

Answer (score 3):

Choosing ASN.1 these days can mean choosing JSON; JSON is now one of ASN.1's wire formats!

**Schema**

However, focusing on schema languages, so far as I can see JSON schema are as capable as ASN.1 schema when it comes to what I consider to be the essentials, i.e. constraints on values and on list sizes. ASN.1's constraints can be quite elaborate - one of the reasons why it's hard to implement tools. Protobuf schema are woefully inadequate in this regard; no constraints, you have to rely on some other means for programmers to understand the valid limits of a value or the acceptable lengths of a list. One feature of ASN.1 schema is that you can declare values, as well as message types, and in the good tools these values show up in generated code. It's extremely powerful, if leveraged properly, because you can have more of your system's constants defined in a single place (the schema file), instead of being hard coded in the various different programming languages used in your system. You can get a very agile workflow happening around that.

**Wire Formats**

Focusing on wire formats, well, ASN.1 wins hands down, featuring a range of different binary wire formats filling a number of different needs, up to both XML and JSON text formats. Protobuf I think can now do JSON, and it has a binary wire format. And JSON is, well, JSON.

The reason why ASN.1 can be so useful in having so many different wire formats is that in some system types it convenient to have data represented in, say JSON/XML in some area, whereas others benefit from uPER (a ultra-compact bit efficient binary wire format). For example, if you're sending data across a bandwidth constrained link, uPER is very handy because you make best use of that bandwidth, but you can store it in (semi)-readable formats like XML or JSON at the endpoints. The tools make it trivial to convert an object from one to the other (deserialise from one wire format, serialise the object to another wire format, job done). Funnily enough, ASN.1 was invented by the telephony business and is used on cellular phone network standards, specifically to save bandwidth (and therefore save costs).

Other benefits of wire formats like BER are that you can tell what message type is being received without reading the whole message; I've found that to be very, very useful in complex systems.

**Tools**

As YaFred has said, it's down to the tools. The best tools for ASN.1 are commercial, and you have to integrate licensing administration into build and deployment. However, given the large degree of development agility that you can get with ASN.1 that you can't quite with Protobuf, I have found that the project cost savings can definitely be worth it. [This one (C only, includes source)](https://bellard.org/ffasn1/) is good and affordable, though if budget stretches to a few thousand dollars I'd take a serious look at [this one](https://www.obj-sys.com/products/asn1c/pricing.php), because of the languages it supports (C/C++, C#, Java, Python, Go)

If you're content with C, there is a reasonably good ASN.1 compiler [here](https://github.com/vlm/asn1c). Currently, this does not do ASN.1 values, and it has some omissions in its constraints handling (specifically, `<`) which is a pity so far as agile workflow goes, but otherwise it's good. It's OSS, so in principle you can fix those omissions yourself without too much difficulty (it's well written, and fairly easy to slot the extra bits and pieces in).

**Come on, Google**

For me, perhaps the best way forward would be for Google to wake up and update Protobuf. They could even do so without touching their wire format. Clunky though their wire format is, the language support for Protobuf is quite good, and free, so it's kinda in the category of "good enough".

But if only they added even simple value and list constraints and value definitions to the schema and code generators; then it would be "complete", in that it would be possible to have the same very agile workflow you can get with ASN.1, but within the free-tooling ecosystem of GPB.

I recall reading at the time Google announced GPB that someone in the conference audience called out, "Why didn't you use ASN.1?". All the virtues that the Googler was claiming for GPB that they'd "invented" (compact data representation, language independence, etc) were things that ASN.1 and the tools for it had had nailed for decades, and they had to admit Google had never heard of ASN.1. Oh, the irony. Basically, if Google had decided to do a good, free implementation of ASN.1 instead of GPB, they'd have got a much better result.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion,

You will choose JSON or Protobuf for the same reasons your ancestors where choosing SOAP against ASN.1 and CORBA instead of ASN.1

Popularity: how many developers are contributing ... can you get support in forums ... etc ?

Tooling: can you rely on existing tools to generate stubs in a specific programming language ... preferably open source ?

Remember ASN.1 is (only) a set of specifications ... each time you find ASN.1 more powerful in definitions, you bump on the same question: what tool can I use to generate my code ? ...

Answer (score 1):

Most people think of the BER family of encoding rules when they think of ASN.1, and that's a tag-length-value encoding system, which means it's unnecessarily redundant and inefficient and ugly.  Instead people should use PER or -better yet- OER.  But the open source tooling around ASN.1 is generally not that widely available, especially for encoding rules that aren't in the BER family.  As a result few *can* use ASN.1 as well as other notations and encoding rules.

It has always been thus.  ASN.1 hails from 1984, and there were no tools, and the specifications back then were not freely available.  Meanwhile, ONC/RPC (1986) and DCE RPC (circa 1988) came with open specifications *and* freely available tools (which later became open source).

Few have put the effort into making decent ASN.1 tooling, and everyone tends to think it's better to re-invent the wheel than to write ASN.1 tooling.

The irony is that Protocol Buffers is a tag-length-value encoding, which is why alternatives like Flat Buffers exist.

As for JSON...  JSON is very convenient for some things, and is schema-free first, which means it's easier to user right up until it's not, then you need JSON Schema or similar.

By the way, ASN.1 has XML and JSON encoring rules...  ASN.1 is essentially a universal abstract syntax notation.  It should be possible to even create Protocol Buffers and Flat Buffers compatible encoding rules for ASN.1 so that one could use ASN.1 modules.

In short: the early non-free (pricy!) ASN.1 specifications + the poor choice of encoding rules technology (tag-length-value) + competition + a strong cultural dislike of ASN.1 kept ASN.1 tooling from being as widely available as needed to "win".  This is sad because ASN.1 is in fact extremely rich in all the ways that matter, and can support most of the encoding systems out there.